# nodejs mocha es6 modules unexpected token export without babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, es6-modules

I am trying to run with some unit test with mocha on ES6 modules with the following command:

```
node --experimental-modules .\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha --reporter progress "client/assets/utils/url-utils.test.mjs"
```

But I get the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export class URLUtils {
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Isn't the `--experimental-modules` param supposed to let me use ES6 modules? I would prefer to avoid using Babel or other transpilers for this.

Node version: 11.7.0

Mocha version: 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

In order to run **mocha with experimental modules**, you should:

1. install mocha-erm: `npm install mocha-esm --only-dev`
2. run your tests with `npx mocha client/assets/utils/url-utils.test.mjs -r esm`

Comment: I get this error documented (and unsolved) on [mocha-esm github](https://github.com/stefanpenner/mocha-esm/issues/9)